# Validação de JSON com mais de um objeto

Tags: java, json

Preciso enviar um JSON a partir de uma `String`.  Ao ler uma série como abaixo, funciona perfeitamente:

```
json = {"resultado":" resultado 111","peso":98,"sinal":"-44","nome":"divergencia ativos","quantidade":12}
```

Mas quando há mais de uma série, como abaixo, dá erro de JSON não válido:

```js
{
    "resultado":" resultado 111",
    "peso":98,
    "sinal":"-44",
    "nome":"divergencia ativos",
    "quantidade":12
}, 
{
    "resultado":" resultado   222",
    "peso":99,
    "sinal":"45",
    "nome":"divergencia geral",
    "quantidade":5
}
```

Como estou usando:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

JsonElement jsonTree = parser.parse(json.toString());
if (jsonTree.isJsonObject()) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject();

    object.put("nome", jsonObject.get("nome").getAsString());
    object.put("peso", jsonObject.get("peso").getAsDouble());
    object.put("quantidade", jsonObject.get("quantidade").getAsDouble());
    object.put("sinal", jsonObject.get("sinal").getAsString());
    object.put("resultado", jsonObject.get("resultado").getAsString());
    listaObject.add(object);
}
```

Comment: Não entendo muito de Java mas seu `json` é um array. Talvez algo do tipo `JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("nomeCampo");` te ajude!

Comment: JSON com dois objetos no topo não é válido. Ou você mete os dois numa array ou em outro objeto.  O topo tem de ser um único objeto ou array.

Comment: @MarceloVismari Na verdade é *quase* um array, faltou estar tudo entre `[ ]` - veja [minha resposta] abaixo :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dá erro de JSON inválido porque o JSON é de fato inválido. De acordo com a [sintaxe de um JSON](http://json.org/), isso aqui é um objeto:

```js
{
    "resultado":" resultado 111",
    "peso":98,
    "sinal":"-44",
    "nome":"divergencia ativos",
    "quantidade":12
}
```

Ele é delimitado por `{ }`, o que quer dizer que depois do `}`, ele se encerra. Se você coloca **outro** objeto logo depois dele, seja separado por vírgula ou não (da forma que está o seu JSON, por exemplo), então você tem 2 objetos "soltos", e [isso é inválido](https://jsonformatter.org/39cc20).

Se você quer ter vários elementos em uma mesma estrutura, uma opção seria usar um array. E de acordo com a sintaxe JSON, um array deve ser delimitado por `[ ]`, e os elementos separados por vírgula. Se o seu JSON estivesse assim, por exemplo:

```js
[
  {
    "resultado":" resultado 111",
    "peso":98,
    "sinal":"-44",
    "nome":"divergencia ativos",
    "quantidade":12
  }, 
  {
    "resultado":" resultado   222",
    "peso":99,
    "sinal":"45",
    "nome":"divergencia geral",
    "quantidade":5
  }
]
```

Aí ele seria válido, pois agora é um array (está delimitado por `[ ]`) contendo dois elementos (os dois objetos), separados por vírgula. Claro que esta é só uma opção, a forma ideal vai depender de cada caso.

---

#### Então como arrumar?

A primeira opção é **corrigir o problema na origem**. Se os dados devem ser um JSON, então quem gera esses dados deveria gerar um JSON válido, "simples" assim.

Outra opção - menos indicada, mas se não for possível mudar os dados na origem, "fazer o que" - é tentar contornar o JSON inválido tornando-o válido.

Já que o JSON inválido tem 2 objetos separados por vírgula, bastaria colocar tudo entre `[ ]` para que ele se torne um array (pelas classes e métodos, estou assumindo que você está usando o [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)):

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
// colocar entre "[" e "]" para virar um array
JsonElement jsonTree = parser.parse("[ " + json.toString() + " ]");
if (jsonTree.isJsonArray()) {
    JsonArray array = jsonTree.getAsJsonArray();
    for (JsonElement element : array) { // percorre os elementos do array
        if (element.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();

            object.put("nome", jsonObject.get("nome").getAsString());
            object.put("peso", jsonObject.get("peso").getAsDouble());
            object.put("quantidade", jsonObject.get("quantidade").getAsDouble());
            object.put("sinal", jsonObject.get("sinal").getAsString());
            object.put("resultado", jsonObject.get("resultado").getAsString());
            listaObject.add(object);
        }
    }
}
```

Isso funciona inclusive quando só há um objeto, pois neste caso será gerado um array com apenas um elemento, e o código funciona do mesmo jeito.

Mas novamente reitero que esta solução é um "remendo", e que o ideal é que os dados gerados já fossem um JSON válido, para que você não precise ficar arrumando manualmente, o que dependendo do caso pode ser bem propenso a erros.

---

Só não entendi porque você está criando outro objeto igual (com as mesmas chaves e valores do `jsonObject` obtido). Mas como não ficou claro o que são `object` e `listaObject`, deixo o código acima apenas como referência.

Comment: Muito obrigado.  Segui tuas dicas e consegui resolver.  Abraço.

Answer (score -2):

O seu JSON com 2 objetos é um array, logo deve-se usar o `JsonArray`, percorrer o array e ai sim usar o `JsonObject`.

Answer (score -2):

```
JsonArray value = Json.createArrayBuilder()
     .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("resultado", " resultado 111")
         .add("peso", 98)
         .add("sinal", "-44")
         .add("nome", "divergencia ativos")
         .add("quantidade", 12))
     .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("resultado", " resultado 222")
         .add("peso", 99)
         .add("sinal", "45")
         .add("nome", "divergencia geral")
         .add("quantidade", 5))
     .build();
```